# Stuffed up my plasma desktop

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I seem to have inadvertently swapped out my plasma Kubuntu desktop for what seems to be a Debian one. (It now has a green screen with a scroll shape in the middle.)KDE 
I also seem to have lost my taskbar too.
How can I restore my original desktop for kubuntu 18.04

Comment: Back up your data and do a clean re-install?

Comment: What did you do to incur this issue?

Comment: I don't know what I did to incur this sort of result.   I have managed to back up my emails, but I have quite a few gigs of other data as well, so I would rather not do a clean reinstall. Are you sure that is the only option?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

I noticed that there was a small gear icon on the Debian startup page and when I clicked this, there was an option to boot with several different desktops.

I clicked on the plasma one, continued the boot process and everything is good again.